# Does zsh respect the shebang bin/sh so dash can be used?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, zsh

I have a simple script involving a `for` loop from bash that I am trying to get working in zsh. I had assumed that the shebang would ensure a POSIX compliant shell would be used (on my system I have `/bin/sh -> dash*`) so there wouldn't be any issues.

MWE script where `ITEMS` is actually the output of a command that lists packages e.g. `ITEMS=$(pip freeze)`:

```
#!/bin/sh

# ITEMS=$(pip freeze)  # Example of useful command

ITEMS="Item1
Item2
Item3"  # Dummy variable for testing

for ITEM in $ITEMS; do
    echo $ITEM
    echo Complete
done
```

This is the output when I try to run the script in `zsh`:

```
$ source scratch.sh
Item1
Item2
Item3
Complete  # Undesired

$ . ./scratch.sh
Item1
Item2
Item3
Complete  # Undesired

$ bash scratch.sh
Item1
Complete
Item2
Complete
Item3
Complete  # Desired

$ sh scratch.sh
Item1
Complete
Item2
Complete
Item3
Complete  # Desired
```

When I run it in a bash terminal it works fine. I think I've misunderstood how the shebang is interpreted by `zsh`?  Can someone please explain to me how it should be used such that when I run `source scratch.sh` or `. ./scratch.sh` I have the same output as if I had run `sh scratch.sh`? I know I could modify my for loop script to be compliant with `zsh` and `bash` natively, but I want to use `/bin/sh -> dash` so I'm always using a posix compliant shell and don't have to worry about bashisms or zshisms.

Apologies if this is a basic question, I did search for `zsh`, `posix` and shebang but didn't find a similar question.

Comment: `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `/bin/dash*`. If you want it to run with `dash`, then just run it as `./scratch.sh`. The shebang is already `#!/bin/sh`.

Comment: Besides, the `echo $ITEM` in your `./scratch.sh` is asking for trouble -- eg. `ITEM="-n \nq"; echo $ITEM` manages to do something different in dash, bash, zsh and ksh.

Comment: On most non-ancient systems -- when given as the _command_ and not as an argument to some (other) command -- this syntax is interpreted by the kernel not zsh or any other shell, and for that reason is now called a kerbang.

Comment: The first UNIX clone `UNOS` from 1980 introduced user space support for `#!` in 1984 in their default shell. All other platforms I am aware of only support `#!` in the kernel and that won't help you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The shebang only has an affect if you execute the script directly *without specifying how to run it*; that is, with something like `./scratch.sh` or `/path/to/scratch.sh` or by putting it in a directory in your `PATH` and just using `scratch.sh`.

If you run it using some other command, that controls what's done with it (overriding the shebang). If you use `bash scratch.sh`, it runs in `bash`; if you use `zsh scratch.sh`, it runs in `zsh`; if you use `sh`, it runs in whatever `sh` is on your system (`dash` in your specific case).

If you use `source scratch.sh` or `. scratch.sh`, it runs in *the current shell*, whatever that is. That's the entire purpose of the `.` and `source` commands. And again, the shebang is ignored here.

Comment: Awesome, makes perfect sense. I'll add a `scripts` folder to my path and go from there.

Comment: This is great information. Will you add sources to this for validation and further exploration?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. `. script` or `source script` simply includes `script`, it doesn't fork a separate standard or non-standard shell to do it. As to shebangs, for `zsh` (when you *source* a script rather than *execute* it) they're just comments.

You can instruct `zsh` to (try to) temporarily emulate a standard shell, though. YMMV.

```
emulate sh -c '. ./scratch.sh'
```

`emulate which_sh -c str` will evaluate `str` with the specified emulation temporarily in effect, and more importantly, will make it "stick" to any functions defined during the evaluation of `str`, causing the emulation mode to be turned on automatically during their execution.

Comment: While the shebang is intended for the kernel and meant to be ignored (treated as a comment here) by the interpreter, zsh like a few other shells, will try to interpret that shebang by itself if `execve()` fails with ENOEXEC. That allows running scripts on systems that don't support shebangs (rare these days), but also avoid running sh on the file like other shells including bash would if there is a shebang specified with a non-executable interpreter.

Comment: My answer is just about sourcing the file in the current shell, not about running it as a separate process. Thanks about the `-c`, I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: My first comment was  a note in reply to *As to shebangs, for zsh they're just comments*.

Comment: Feel free to improve the answer, and make it less awkward.