# Tar exclude parameter in bash script not working

Tags: bash, ubuntu, gnu-tar

I got a tar command line that works great straight in the shell.

```
tar --exclude=out/pictures/\*.{jpg,gif,png,jpeg} --exclude=tmp/\*.{txt,php} --exclude=log/\*.{log,sql} -cvf /backups/mydomain.tar -C /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs content
```

As soon as I put this command in a bash script and execute, it ignores the excludes parameters.

I tried some various syntax like:

```
tar --exclude="out/pictures/\*.{jpg,gif,png,jpeg}" -cvf /backups/mydomain.tar -C /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs content

tar --exclude='out/pictures/\*.{jpg,gif,png,jpeg}' -cvf /backups/mydomain.tar -C /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs content

tar --exclude out/pictures/\*.{jpg,gif,png,jpeg} -cvf /backups/mydomain.tar -C /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs content

tar --exclude= out/pictures/\*.{jpg,gif,png,jpeg} -cvf /backups/mydomain.tar -C /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs content
```

But nothing works. The exclude parameters are simply ignored.

A simple --exclude like `--exclude="tmp"` works as intended. As soon I start to work with parameters it breaks cause of the syntax I assume.

Im running tar (GNU tar) 1.29 on ubuntu 18.04.5.

Comment: Welcome, you should use an absolute path: `/abs/path/out/pictures/` if the script is not in the same directory.

Comment: This is no absolute path problem. Things like `--exclude=out/pictures` works grea but `--exclude=out/pictures/\*.{jpg,gif,png,jpeg}` dont work.

Comment: The original command-line syntax should work as-is. You're escaping the asterisk character so that the shell does not expand it, but you're also letting the shell expand the `{jpg,gif,png,jpeg}` part. Are you sure that the command doesn't work, when copy-pasted as is?

Comment: What is the shebang? Are you sure the shell interpreting the script expands `{jpg,gif,png,jpeg}`? This syntax is *not* portable.

Comment: An off-the-wall work-around: (a) mv -t /somewhere out/pictures (on the same device so it does a cheap move, not an expensive copy). (b) Run  tar without the excludes. (c) mv -t httpdocs out/pictures.

Comment: Less off-the-wall: mark those excluded directories as *caches*, using one of the options `--exclude-caches-all` or `--exclude-tag-all`. You might at least get a better class of bug.

Answer (score 0):

The brace expansion only works in bash and not sh.
Make sure your shebang is set to bash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Make your script executable and call it directly

```
chmod +x myscript.sh
./myscript.sh
```

You can always verify the expansion by putting an echo in front of your command.

```
echo tar --exclude=out/pictures/\*.{jpg,gif,png,jpeg} --exclude=tmp/\*.{txt,php} --exclude=log/\*.{log,sql} -cvf /backups/mydomain.tar -C /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs content
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I learned something essential today.

The bash shell supports the brace expansion. The sh shell (is the sh a shell?) however not.

And by running the script with `sh myscript.sh` like I did, the script was executed with the sh shell. `bash myscript.sh` works instant.

But shouldn't the link `#!/bin/bash` in the sh file force the script to execute anyway with bash?

Can someone explain? Im a bit confused.

> Running it as ./script.sh will make the kernel read the first line
> (the shebang), and then invoke bash to interpret the script. Running
> it as sh script.sh uses whatever shell your system defaults sh to (on
> Ubuntu this is Dash, which is sh-compatible, but doesn't support some
> of the extra features of Bash).

This would explain everything but the default shell `echo $SHELL` on my ubuntu is bash (this quote is from 2010 so I assume back then the default shell was dash on ubuntu).

I would like to understand it, even if it works with `bash myscript.sh`.

Comment: If you explicitly run a script with `sh`, it does not examine the SHELL variable. It just finds the first `sh` on the current path. That may be a real Bourne `sh`, but more usually it is a link to (or copy of) the POSIX-conforming shell in that distro -- may be dash or ksh or something else. When you explicitly run a script with a given shell, it just reads the script as text, so the shebang is just a comment. Only the kernel actions the shebang, when it finds the script as an executable.

Comment: Please see [how the site is supposed to work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour). My main point: do not ask a follow-up question in an answer.

Comment: An explicit interpreter (e.g. `sh myscript.sh` or `bash myscript.sh`) takes precedence over the shebang line (see my answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/580124/does-zsh-respect-the-shebang-bin-sh-so-dash-can-be-used)). `$SHELL` is not relevant -- that's the default interactive shell for your user account, and has no effect on scripts (unless you use `source` or `.` to run the script *in* your interactive shell).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification Paul_Pedant and Gordon Davisson.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try:

```
tar --exclude="out/pictures/*.{jpg,gif,png,jpeg}" -cvf /backups/mydomain.tar -C "/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs content"
```